# nested component can't get props through connect

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-props

I am using a connected component as a props passed to a parent component, but I can't get any props from connect() or even from the function definition inside the component.

I have tried to defined the props function in render() but still not work

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Col,Row} from 'antd'
import injectSheet from 'react-jss';

class SubComponent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

    }
    picClicked=()=>{
        console.log("cause state!");
        console.log(this.props.picClicked);// output undefined
        this.props.picClicked;
    }
    render(){

        const {picClicked,classes} = this.props;// classes is from react-jss

        console.log(this.props);// only classes is shown from the console log
        return(
            <div>
                <div onClick={this.picClicked} className={classes.headBlank}>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
}
SubComponent.propTypes={
    picClicked:PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
export default injectSheet(logoStyle)(SubComponent)
```

then the container looks like following:

```
const mdtp = (dispatch)=>{
    return{
        picClicked:()=>{console.log("picClicked!");}
    };
};

export default connect(null,mdtp)(SubComponent);
```

The SubComponent is then used as a props in another parent component like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={storeMainContents}>
            <ParentComponent  contentsShow={<SubComponent />} />
        </Provider>
        ,document.getElementById("parentComponent")

);
```

The parent component looks like this:

```
render(){

        const {contentsShow,classes}=this.props;

        return(
            <div>
                <div>
                    {this.props.contentsShow}

                </div>
            </div>
            );
    }
```

What I expected is that the SubComponent can access the props like picClicked as a action that can be dispatched or at least get accessed. Now it is simply undefined.

Comment: can you add the imports of `subComponent` ?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi Sure, thanks in advance

Comment: You create a `<SubComponent/>`, without _any_ props, in some out-of-component scope (so it doesn't even _have_ a true parent compenent) so... I'm not sure why you'd expect this to work? If the parent has to build it, make it do that in its own `render` function and pass in the function it needs to call as prop?

Comment: I have never worked with `react-jss` but besides that, why do you have two times export default of `SubComponent` ? it was better to do something like `const SubWithStyles = injectSheet....` then `export default connect (...)(SubWithStyle)`.
Or maybe I am totally wrong :)

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi they are in 2 files, the one export injectSheet()()  is supposed to be a dumb component which is actually not, the second is to use connect to provide the props definition like redux is supposed to behave.

Comment: Sorry for not beeing any help, but assume [these sandboxs](https://github.com/cssinjs/react-jss/issues/180#issuecomment-344221619) might gives you some hint

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I had make this kind of nested work in other parts of my code before, the SubComponent is not supposed to have data exchange with parent component, it is only to show a part of the page, they only share the same store. Yes, I also feel I should not do it like this now.

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi Thank you very much!

Comment: React is a _ui_ framework, so if they're part of the same page,and the subcomponent is presented in the parent component, then you really shouldn't be doing things this way. The parent should just be building (and tearing down) the subcomponent as needed. The code you show here just makes no sense if the idea is to follow React's approach to things.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The idea is to make a framework with header and footer so it could be shared by all pages, so the content should be passed to this page as a props. I had make it work by passing the sub component written directly in the parent component like <subcomponent /> which is also a connected part, but it can not be passed as a props. The problem for me now is what is a prop in react and the official document give some explanation in sector composition and inheritance. The composition example only mention class without props, so I am still confused in it and might make a new post.